# Best Hermeneutical Approach for a Bible Study for Atheists

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, tools-of-biblical-studies

This study would arm members when attacked using Scripture and would help people in their post-Christian and post-Jewish transition.

I would like to, in some orderly fashion, get through the entire Christian Bible, but I don't know where to start. I am pretty familiar with it, but the last time I took a class in hermeneutics was in the late 80's from a dispensationalist university. What should I read before I start?

Comment: Where to start... I'm thinking of Dorothy and how she asked the same question and Glinda, the Good Witch, who said: "It's always best to start at the beginning." Sorry my answer isn't more formal but this makes sense to me. Matthew is the beginning and there are plenty of good one-liners in that book. The NT is shorter than a standard novel (less than 300 pages).  ;-)

Comment: “Begin at the beginning," the King said, very gravely, "and go on till you come to the end: then stop.” Most other stackexchange sites sites close this type of question "as off-topic" or "opinion based", or "too broad".

Comment: That's true but an atheist that wants to read scriptures -if this doesn't deserve support, I don't know what does. Thanks for the Lewis Carroll quote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you know about the Bible is based on dispensationalist studies around 30 years ago, this was in many ways different to mainstream Christianity, and your hermeneutic studies were probably biased towards supporting a dispensationalist understanding. Since you are not merely interested in debating dispensationalists, you probably need to have a broader understanding of what Christians believe, so the first place to start is to learn what other Christians believe. Given the intellectual challenge you would be setting yourself in both learning more about Christianity and modern hermeneutics, I even suggest asking yourself whether this is something you really want to do.

Hermeneutics means different things to different people. Critical scholars use the historical-critical method, which Manfred Oeming describes in *[Contemporary Biblical Hermeneutics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0754656608)* as one of the prime achievements of academic theology. this book will give you an introduction to the method, as well as to other hermeneutic methods used by non-academics.

It is a tenet of the historical-critical method that the Bible should be read and analysed as literature, in the same way as any other book would be read and analysed: it is therefore not divinely inspired unless there is actual evidence of divine inspiration.  Similarly, miracles are accepted as real only after all other explanations have been ruled out.

If you want to understand the Bible, don't make the mistake of starting from Genesis and working through, book by book, in an "orderly fashion".  Find out how the books relate to each other and in what chronological order. Learn about different views, from conservative to liberal, of when books were written, by whom and in what context.  Then create a plan of what you want to study, and start reading, making notes as you go.

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the only answer that fully addresses my question and doesn't go off on tangents.

Comment: This is an amazing Answer! :-O Can believe, it doesn't get more upvotes...  Thanks Dick!

Answer (score 2):

If your going for a study of the bible you need to start with the gospel. Identifying who Christ is and what he did. Paul preaches that we are set apart from the law of sin and death by the law of the spirit which is refering to our indwelling of the holy spirit. You need to know God's commandments and you can't do that Well without knowing the law. So I would strongly suggest genesis through Deuteronomy after going through the new testament. And to better know the new testament you need to know the old testament and the history of God's people especially the prophets concerning judgement because God is our judge. The work of the spirit was manifested in Christ but has been evident throughout all scripture. What you're aiming for is knowing the commandments because we are in the middle of a war between God and the devil, light and darkness and you need to make sure your on Christ's side who fulfills life.

Comment: This is typical glib Christian answer - one that doesn't think about the question being asked.  Would an atheist see a need for Christ given that an atheist doesn't even believe in God?  Why not meet the atheist where they're at - and challenge their disbelief in God first before presenting Christ?  Is it rational to believe that '**life comes from non-life**' given that all our science has ever seen is life arising from life?  Or how about the origin of the universe?  Get the atheist wondering about their disbelief first.  Paul had it right with **1 Corinthians 9:19-23**.

Comment: Yikes! This is Tyler's first time here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not indicate whether you intend to subscribe to the same hermeneutical approach you studied in the 1980's.

Assuming you are disposed to approach a different approach, one option would be to follow a patristic hermeneutic - i.e. attempting to read and understand the Bible as the Church Fathers understood it.  If this is an approach that interests you, then I would start with the New Testament - especially the Gospels - and follow the commentary of the 11th century Byzantine Theophylact of Ohrid, who summarized earlier patristic commentaries.  His four volumes of Gospel commentaries are [available in paperback form from Chrysostom Press](http://www.chrysostompress.org/catalog_explanation_s.html).  Another valuable resource to support this approach is also the [two volume *Orthodox New Testament*](http://holyapostlesconvent.org:8081/hacwebstore/searchresults.zul?categoryID=2), which contains pages and pages of footnotes with commentaries usually originating from the first half of the first millennium.